# Xcode "step in" debugger problem

Tags: xcode, gdb

I have a problem when using step in a function - the debugger jumps in a header file that is not related with the implementation of that function. This is working as expected for other functions.. Did you have such problems before? What did you do to solve this? It's very weird.. I never had such problem in Xcode before. I tried to disable compile for thumb option as I saw as a solution in other threads, but I still have the problem.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: In call stack function name is correct, but if I I double click it, it takes me in the same place as the debugger

Comment: Even if I pus a break point in the function the debugger takes me other file...

Comment: Yes, it is a c++ static function from a class. The function is implemented in a cpp file that doesn't have same name as the header file.